# ESP8266 Timezone issues

Tags: esp8266, arduino-esp8266

I'm having some issues with timezone in esp8266

I'm getting +8 hours over the timezone that I config. I though that it was a bug in my code.

After some tests, i saw that the problem was since the beginning

```
    void setup() {

      if(ESP.getResetReason() != "Power on") {
         WiFi.mode(WIFI_OFF);
      }  
      Serial.begin(115200); 

      pinMode(PIN_RESETTODEFAULT,INPUT_PULLUP);
         time_t now;
         unsigned int currentime=time(&now);
         struct tm *timeinfo = localtime(&now);
         Serial.printf("HH:MM1: %d-%d-%d %d:%d:%d\r\n",timeinfo->tm_mday,timeinfo->tm_mon,timeinfo->tm_year,timeinfo->tm_hour,timeinfo->tm_min,timeinfo->tm_sec);
```

This code is returning me:

```
08:51:17.031 -> SDK:2.2.1(cfd48f3)/Core:2.4.2/lwIP:2.0.3(STABLE-2_0_3_RELEASE/glue:arduino-2.4.1-13-g163bb82)/BearSSL:6d1cefc
08:51:17.066 -> HH:MM1: 1-0-70 8:0:0
08:51:17.066 ->
```

If i set the hour from internet using ConfigTime the problem continues, even if I set the timezone properly.

It looks like a internal setting problem, a value in a register or something like that , but I dont get it, but i do this to config it right and i get those 8 aditional hours anyways:

```
configTime(0, 0, "pool.ntp.org", "time.nist.gov"); 
setenv("TZ", "CET-1CEST,M3.5.0,M10.5.0/3", 0);
```

Trying to reset the internal registers I do

```
configTime(0, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL);
setenv("TZ", "", 0);
tzset();
```

And then I get the right time for my zone, but this is not right

As I said, probably i'm missing something, but in all the examples I see the same stuff. Any tip is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally and after some hours trying different stuff, this worked for me:

```
void InitTimeZone()
{
  struct timezone tz={0,0};
  struct timeval tv={0,0};
  settimeofday(&tv, &tz);  
  setenv("TZ", "CET-1CEST,M3.5.0,M10.5.0/3", 0);
  tzset();
}
```

It seems like an internal register, but I dont get it. And i have to do that each time that the chip starts.